# Calling a variable from child class in parent class in c#

Tags: c#, oop, console-application

I am trying to raed the value of userInput variable in my parent class which is stored in my child class, but I can't reach it and I get many errors one after one after each try. Can you please help me?

This is apart of my code:

```
//Child class
class tictactoe
{
     public void beginGame()
     {
        ConsoleKeyInfo gebruikerInvoer;
        gebruikerInvoer = Console.ReadKey();
        //Rest of code
      }
}

//Parent class
namespace Quizz
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            tictactoe minigame1 = new tictactoe();
            while (minigame1.gebruikerInvoer)
            {
                //Rest of code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get

```
'tictactoe' does not contain a definition for 'gebruikerInvoer' and no accessible extension method 'gebruikerInvoer' accepting a first argument of type 'tictactoe' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I think that I will need to make a method to call it from the parent, if so: what type should I give since the variable is a ConsoleKeyInfo that is later converted to string?

```
gebruikerInvoer.KeyChar.ToString()
```

Comment: You can't. Variables are essentially labels to a storage location used inside a code block. You need to use a *public property* if you want something to be visible to other classes.

Comment: Yes I was almost sure that I can't so I've edited the question to maybe a better one

Comment: I've also forgot to mention that it is being converted to a string later in the code as mentioned above

Comment: How can you say Program class is parent of tictactoe class

Comment: You define `gebruikerInvoer` var inside `beginGame()` method, so you could not access it as class field

Comment: @GauravChaudhary the whole program is a little quiz, what I am trying to do is creating a different classes for each phase of the quiz, this phase is a tictactoe phase so it is a child class of the program

Comment: @Nerower I've tried that but I get this error 

The type or namespace name 'gebruikerInvoer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Amer Child class is a class that `extends` parent class.

Comment: Putting aside the parent-child interpretation, it seems pretty clear that you need to follow a tutorial on variable scopes. Here one for you https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/variable-scopes-in-csharp?msclkid=268eb237a53a11ecbdee713d6f8f8eb2

Comment: I would also suggest separating your input/output from your game logic. Having your TicTacToe class reading input from the console is a good way to ensure that it is difficult to test with automated tools.

Comment: I would also advice following some [Code Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) to make the code easier to read.

Comment: `gebruikerInvoer` is a local variable in your beginGame() function in your tictactoe class, it is **not** visible to outside world. If you need to access it from code in Program class, then have a public property or function in tictactoe class to return the 'gebruikerInvoer', but then you need to instantiate on the heap, not on stack.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments have made apparent, you need to first make the variable visible to the outside world. Local variables are always hidden from other classes. So lets fix this first:

```
    class tictactoe
    {
        public ConsoleKeyInfo gebruikerInvoer; //Make public and move owner to class not method
        public void beginGame()
        {
            gebruikerInvoer = Console.ReadKey();
            //Rest of code
        }
    }

    //Parent class
    namespace Quizz
    {
        class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                tictactoe minigame1 = new tictactoe();
                while (minigame1.gebruikerInvoer) //CS0029 ConsoleKeyInfo cannot be implicitly converted to type Bool
                {
                    //Rest of code
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Moving on from there you need to define a statement to test the variable's value in a way that can return a true or false statement to use a `while` loop. To fix that we can do something like this:

```
    class tictactoe
    {
        public ConsoleKeyInfo gebruikerInvoer;
        public void beginGame()
        {
            gebruikerInvoer = Console.ReadKey();
            //Rest of code
        }
    }

    //Parent class
    namespace Quizz
    {
        class Program
        {
            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                tictactoe minigame1 = new tictactoe();
                bool minigameRun = minigame1.gebruikerInvoer.KeyChar == 't' 
                    ? true : false; //Assign a true value if the user entered the letter 't', else false
                while (minigameRun) //Runs rest of code while minigameRun is true
                {
                    //Rest of code
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then to escape the while loop you can use `return`, `break`, or upon some condition change the local `bool` minigameRun to false. The `bool` is initially assigned in this code using the `?:` operator. You can read more about its use [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: I was thinking of examples like `public class Foo { private int Value = 42; private class Bar : Foo { public void Qaz() { Console.WriteLine(this.Value); } } }`, but that's not a local variable. Otherwise, the prime example is capture of local variables.